# Why std::function::argument_type has been deprecated?

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer, deprecated, c++17

I've seen on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) that `std::function::argument_type` was deprecated in C++17. What is the reason behind it? And what ISO WG21 paper was proposing that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The relevant papers are [P0005R4](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0005r4.html) (which is the paper that was voted into the draft standard) and [P0090R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0090r0.htm) (which is referenced by P0005R4).

Quotes from P0090R0:

> Q2. What's wrong with result_type, etc.?
>
> A2. These C++98/03/TR1-era typedefs predated decltype and perfect
>   forwarding. Previously, generic code had to request information from
>   function objects before adapting them.  Now, manually communicating
>   that information is unnecessary.  decltype supersedes result_type,
>   because the compiler can simply report what the result of calling a
>   function object with specific arguments will be.  And perfect
>   forwarding supersedes the argument_type family, since adaptors can
>   simply take/store/forward arbitrary arguments.
>
> In fact, these typedefs are worse than useless.  They're
>   counterproductive, because many callable objects lack them.  Function
>   pointers and pointers to members have always lacked them.  ptr_fun(),
>   which wrapped function pointers with these typedefs, was recently
>   removed (see [1] again).  Most importantly, lambdas have always lacked
>   these typedefs, and they are the most important function objects of
>   all.  Generic lambdas are even more incompatible.
>
> What this means is that if a user attempts to write generic code by
>   using the result_type family of typedefs, their code won't be generic
>   - it'll fail to handle lambdas, generic lambdas, function pointers, etc.
>
> These typedefs should be removed because they've become actively
>   harmful to modern code.

Answer (score 9):

The reason those typedefs exist are so things like [`not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1), [`bind1st`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) and friends, could query the callables passed to them and retrieve the type of the result of invoking the callable, its argument types etc.

To make their use palatable, a lot of support machinery, like [`unary_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function), [`ptr_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun), [`mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) etc. were also defined. Notice how all of these are limited to adapting callables taking one or two arguments only, so they're rather limited in that sense.

Now that we have `decltype` that can be used to deduce a callable's return type, variadic templates and perfect forwarding to forward arbitrary number of arguments to functions, etc. the pre-C++11 mechanisms are way too cumbersome to use.

Stephan T Lavavej first proposed getting rid of these in C++17 in [p0090r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0090r0.htm). Relevant excerpts from the paper:

> Q1. What are you proposing?
>   * Removing every mention of `result_type`, `argument_type`, `first_argument_type`, and `second_argument_type` ...
>   * Removing the negators `not1()` and `not2()`, which were powered by these
>   typedefs.
>   
>   Q2. What's wrong with `result_type`, etc.?
>   A2. These C++98/03/TR1-era typedefs predated `decltype` and perfect forwarding. Previously, generic code had to request information from function objects before adapting them.  Now, manually communicating that information is unnecessary.  `decltype` supersedes `result_type`, because the compiler can simply report what the result of calling a function object with specific arguments will be.  And perfect forwarding supersedes the `argument_type` family, since adaptors can simply take/store/forward arbitrary arguments.

If you search the paper for `[func.wrap.func]`, it talks specifically about removing the `std::function` typedefs you're asking about.