# Functor's argument_type considered bad: how to replace it?

Tags: c++

I have been intrigued by `std::function`'s `argument_type` being deprecated. The response given to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907454/why-stdfunctionargument-type-has-ben-deprecated) references a paper that actually goes further, implying that `result_type` and similar type definitions to be old/bad practice. The paper suggests in particular that perfect forwarding killed the need for `argument_type`.

Is that always so however? Sometimes you do want to have the type of the argument to do more elaborate things than just forwarding. For example, a numerical optimization object may take a functor to minimize as a template argument, and use its `argument_type` to deduce the input's precision and therefore adapt stopping criteria constants accordingly.

Would there be a more post-C++11 way than typedefs to do that? Is there a way to deduce automatically the type of the argument without having to specify it again in one form or another? Or are those kind of constructions (a class depending on the argument type of another) also considered bad practice, and what would be an alternative implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907454/why-stdfunctionargument-type-has-ben-deprecated

Comment: @Damian I actually mention this link as it is the starting point of my question...

Comment: Sorry missed that. Still believe that it answers all your questions?

Comment: It does not answer my questions, it caused them.